# manage signals in GTK .ui files in vala

Tags: gtk3, vala

from the following .ui files, I have the signal :

```
     <object class="GtkButton" id="button2">
        <property name="label">Button 2</property>
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="receives_default">False</property>
        <signal name="clicked" handler="on_button2_clicked" swapped="no"/>
      </object>
```

the name of signal `on_button2_clicked` and the following code I used to handle event by `add_callback_symbool` :

```
    // Create Builder
    var build = new Gtk.Builder ();
    build.add_from_resource ("/me/rush/Rush/main.ui");

    // Create an instance
    var window =  (Gtk.ApplicationWindow) build.get_object ("window");

    // handle event
    build.add_callback_symbol ("on_button2_clicked", ()=> {print ("click");});

    window.application = app;
    window.show_all ();
```

GUI appeard in screen but handling of event `on_button2_clicked` doesnt work, I tried to handle event with `build.connect_signals (null)` and defiend function with same name but also doesnt work

when googling I found a way to work with callbaks in templates, but what I want to do is handle event with `connect.signals` or `add_callback_symbol`
also I tried example [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/GTKSample?highlight=(%5CbVala%2FExamples%5Cb)#Loading_User_Interface_from_XML_File) but it doesnt work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also replied this to [your question on GNOME's discourse](https://discourse.gnome.org/t/handle-event-from-ui-file/3511), but I'll post the answer again here for visibility:

> It's maybe good to know that Vala has built-in support for GtkTemplates, which means you don't need to explicitly call the GtkBuilder API anymore. Vala will do the necessary checks for you (at compile-time even).
>
> You can find multiple examples for this in the GNOME Contacts repository, but to give a concrete one, let's show the SetupWindow:
>
> - [The UI definition](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-contacts/-/blob/master/data/ui/contacts-setup-window.ui)
> - [The GResources XML where it gets included](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-contacts/-/blob/master/data/contacts.gresource.xml)
> - [The Vala source code](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-contacts/-/blob/master/src/contacts-setup-window.vala). Look especially for `[GtkTemplate]` and `[GtkChild]`. A speicifcally callback isn't part of this class, but there are examples of this if you look for `[GtkCallback]`